# How to change response from $http.get to camelCase?

Tags: angularjs

My server send me response with next format:

```
{
  Result:{
  },
  AdditionalStatusCode: 200
}
```

and I want to check status code value by name additionalStatusCode(camel  case), but I can't do it. As I know, there is [camelcase-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase-keys) library, but "require"

```
const camelcaseKeys = require('camelcase-keys');
```

is not available.
Can anybody get me some advice, how to fix my problem? How to convert server response to camel case?

Comment: do you have camelcase-keys in your package.json file and did you run npm install?

Comment: @mixim. which version of angular you are using?

Comment: I use AngularJS 1.5.8

Comment: if you are getting a string separated with space between the words then u can write your own function